# Prove that the gcd is 1.

Tags: number-theory

I need to show that for $x$ odd the $\gcd\bigg(x,\dfrac{x^2-1}{2},\dfrac{x^2+1}{2}\bigg)=1$. Im trying it doing it pairwise. I already show that $\gcd\bigg(\dfrac{x^2-1}{2},\dfrac{x^2+1}{2}\bigg)=1$, but I dont have an idea how to show that $\gcd\bigg(x,\dfrac{x^2-1}{2}\bigg)=1$ and $\gcd\bigg(x,\dfrac{x^2+1}{2}\bigg)=1$.

I will appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you show that $\gcd(x, x^2-1) = \gcd(x, x^2+1) = 1$?

Comment: If $p|x$ does it divide $x^2-1$?

Comment: Hint: $\;x \cdot x - 2 \cdot \cfrac{x^2-1}{2} = 1\,$.

Comment: $\gcd(a,b,c) | \gcd(a,b)$ so if $\gcd(a,b) =1$ then $\gcd(a,b,c) =1$ and you don't have to prove anything about $\gcd(a,c)$ or $\gcd(b,c)$.  So if you've proven one of the three pairs, you don't *have* to prove any of the others..... just saying...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since you already proved that $\gcd\left(\frac{x^2-1}{2},\frac{x^2+1}{2}\right)=1$, assume that $\gcd\left(x,\frac{x^2-1}{2},\frac{x^2+1}{2}\right)=d>1$ which means $d \mid \frac{x^2+1}{2}$ and $d \mid \frac{x^2-1}{2}$ or $\gcd\left(\frac{x^2-1}{2},\frac{x^2+1}{2}\right)\geq d>1$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $p|x$ then $p|x^2$ and $p\not |x^2 \pm 1$ so $p\not|\frac{x^2 \pm 1}k$.

So $x$ and $\frac{x^2 \pm 1}2$ have no prime factors in common. So $\gcd(x, \frac{x^2 -1}2) = \gcd(x,\frac{x^2 +1}2) = 1$.

And $\gcd(\frac{x^2-1}2,\frac{x^2 + 1}2) = \gcd(\frac{x^2 -1}2, \frac{x^2 +1}2 - \frac{x^2-1}2) = \gcd(\frac{x^2-1}2, 1) = 1$.